# Bootstrap card description for screen reader

Tags: html, accessibility, bootstrap-5, screen-readers, nvda

I am trying to mark up a Bootstrap 5 card so that when the user hovers over the card, a screen reader reads out the value I have set

Currently, we achieve this by wrapping the entire contents of the .card into an anchor tag and setting an aria-label value

This works and does not seem to break any accessibility markup rules (checked using aXe)

If however the card contains an image, the image alt takes precedence over the anchor's aria-label (if the user hovers over the image, the alt is read out and if anywhere else in the card is hovered over, nothing is read out)

We may also want to have a button on the card (usually in the .card-footer) but again, nothing is read out by the screen reader

How can we markup the card so that

- if the button is hovered over, the label is read out
- if the image is hovered over, the image alt is read out
- if anywhere other than the button or image is hovered over, the card description is read out

Current markup is as follows

```
<div class="card">
<a class="no-underline overflow-hidden" id="card3309" href="/home/" target="_self" aria-label="This is a test description for the card">
        <div aria-labelledby="card3309" role="region">
            <img class="card-img-top" alt="This is your image" src="/media/1016/eqimg2.jpg">
            <div class="card-body p-0"></div>
            <div class="card-footer clearfix">
                <button class="btn eq-btn eq-btn-primary w-100 image-text" tabindex="-1" onclick="location.href = '/yourdetails/';" target="_self" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-bs-original-title="Your Button">Your Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Thanks

Comment: May I ask what the use-case is for having a screen reader read out the cards contents on hover? From the outside, if a user is using hover to read out the contents of a card to the screen reader, it would be better to let them hover over the individual parts of the card that they want read rather than marking the entire card as a single description. As a side note, I recommend implementing your card using https://inclusive-components.design/cards/. Anchor tags cannot really have a button as a descendant as that is invalid HTML (axe won't flag that)

Comment: @StevenLambert, why wouldn't axe flag a 4.1.1 issue?

Comment: @slugolicious Axe isn't designed to validate the HTML as there are already tools designed to do just that.